# rails4 upload file extension error ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile

Tags: actiondispatch

Guy
now i want to upload file with rails 4 
my problem now i can't check the file extension before upload it

Note :  **I can upload the file well**  but i want to get the file kind before upload it

because i need the extension in another step in my App.

I'm tried to use the commands

```
File.extname(params[:Upload])
```

but always got the error

`can't convert ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String`

also how i can get the file base name before upload it ??
when i tryed to use

```
File.basename(params[:Upload])
```

i got the same error

```
can't convert ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String
```

also when i tried to convert the name to Sting i don't get any thing

Answer (score 6):

That's because `File.extname` expects a string file name, but an uploaded file (your `params[:upload]` is an object, it's an instance of the `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` class (kind of a temporary file)

To fix the problem you need to call the `path` property on your `params[:upload]` object, kind of like that

```
File.extname(params[:Upload].path)
```

Btw, if you're trying to get the type of the uploaded file, I'd encourage you to check for the `params[:Upload].content_type` instead, it's harder to spoof

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`params[:Upload].original_filename.split('.').last`

The `original_filename` contains full filename with extension.

so you split it based on `'.'` and last index will contain the file extension.

**For Example:**
`"my_file.doc.pdf".split('.').last # => 'pdf'`

You can check this for more info [ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html).